# How do I enable debug mode in Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have the base version. I read the article http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-debug-module.html but I do not understand in which file to insert the code, which includes debugging?

I searched the information and found that in config/web.php
Now I wrote in it debug in the section YII_ENV_DEV like this:

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        'allowedIPs' => ['85.89.139.124'],
    ];

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        // uncomment the following to add your IP if you are not connecting from localhost.
        //'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1'],
    ];
}
```

app/web/index.php

```
 <?php
       defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
       defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

But it does not work and I see just a 404 error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

check in your app/web/index.php  and be sure you have

```
 <?php
       defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
       defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
         ........
```

Comment: Yes. These are the values I have there are set up.

Comment: Hi @scais: Is there any way to enable debugger tool for particular user? Or, is there any way to initialize debugger tool in my custom controller?

Comment: @NanaPartykar   Hi .. your comment is not clear to me .. explain better

Comment: @scaisEdge: I just posted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51668018/enable-debugger-tool-through-custom-controller-in-yii2 Please have a look. And, sorry for not asking clear question to you.