# Enable debugger tool for particular user through custom controller in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

To enable debugger tool, we modify **web/index.php** file

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'prod');
```

How to override or change these variables in custom controller?

```
class CommonController extends Controller {
  public function init() {
    $user_id = 1;
    if($user_id == 1){
      defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
      defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
    }
  }
}
```

Goal is to enable the debugger for particular user. I know there is a way through `AllowedIps`. But, I was looking for particular user wise. Is it possible?

Comment: these DEBUG  const  .. must be declare before the application run .. so  the question is how you know which user  is running the app at this moment ..?  . the IP is not at the boostrap phase but the user ?

Comment: Yes. That's the problem @scaisEdge. I can't able to know the logged in user id as these constant get defined before the application run. Is there any way?

Comment: .. Could be using session for set the user and then invoke the app ..  cheching for some session var..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Based on this [article](https://sammaye.wordpress.com/2014/11/23/getting-yii2-debug-to-show-on-user-role-instead-of-ip/)

Create a new Class somewhere, I used `common\components\Debug`. Extend it from `yii\debug\Module` and overwrite `checkAccess()`with your required logic.

```
<?php

namespace common\components;

class Debug extends \yii\debug\Module
{
    private $_basePath;

    protected function checkAccess()
    {
        $user = \Yii::$app->getUser();

        if (
            $user->identity &&
            $user->can('admin')
        ) {    
            return true;
        }
        //return parent::checkAccess();
    }

    /**
     * @return string root directory of the module.
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     */
    public function getBasePath()
    {
        if ($this->_basePath === null) {
            $class = new \ReflectionClass(new \yii\debug\Module('debug'));
            $this->_basePath = dirname($class->getFileName());
        }

        return $this->_basePath;
    }
}
```

Then update your `main-local.php` for the app(s) you need it

```
if (!YII_ENV_TEST) {
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = [
        'class' => 'common\components\Debug', // <--- Here
    ];

    ...
}
```

This will of course run the debugger for all users, but only display it for the administrators. This might have some unwanted overhead on your application, but the debugging process starts before the identity is checked.